# Why wont my data filter the date .. smalldatetime

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

```
SELECT S.studentID, S.studentFName, S.DOB, S.studentEMail, S.studentAddress
FROM Student AS S RIGHT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT Attendance.studentID, COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Attendance CROSS JOIN
CourseUnit WHERE (Attendance.attStatus = 'Yes') AND (CourseUnit.courseCode = 'S3000') AND (CONVERT(VARCHAR, Attendance.attDate, 101) < '11/10/2010') GROUP BY Attendance.studentID
HAVING (COUNT(*) < 5)) AS A ON A.studentID = S.studentID
```

Everything works, except the `attDate`. I dont have any records in 2010, and it still brings up all of them ??

Comment: Why are you treating dates as strings? SQL Server knows how to compare dates, and will do so sensibly. Converting to strings opens up all kinds of possibilities for errors.

Comment: What datatype is Attendance.attDate?

Comment: CONVERT(VARCHAR, Attendance.attDate, 101) why converting to varchar

Answer (score 1):

Let me guess - your dates are a varchar? Fired. Any reason for that ugly ugly ugly unperformant and error prone construct

(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Attendance.attDate, 101) < '11/10/2010')

instead of Attendance.attDate being a Date object to start with? Try that and see whether that works.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't you saying 'give me all dates less than this day in 2010' (`< '2/10/2010'`)?

Maybe you need to switch around your `<` to a `>`.

Comment: Yes, but that was just a test to see if it would bring up any results.

Comment: @David What exactly are you trying to get it to do, and what is it doing?  Show us some sample output.  Also can you try to clean up the code a bit? There's extra whitespace everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

`Attendance.attDate` should be of data type `datetime` and the comparison should be `Attendance.attDate < '20101110'` (YYYYMMDD) if you want the rows prior to the given date value.